# How to avoid instant saving of the model with ajax validation?

Tags: yii2

I want to add Ajax validation to check the form before updating. In the view, added to the required field

```
['enableAjaxValidation' => true]
```

In the controller in the actionUpdate

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $modelForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            if ($modelForm->validate()) {
                $model->setAttributes($modelForm->getAttributes());

                if ($model->save()) {
                    return $this->redirect([my way]);
                }

                if ($model->hasErrors()) {
                    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
                } else {
                    return ['success' => 1, 'html' =>
                        $this->renderPartial('view', [my data];
                }
            } else {
                return ActiveForm::validate($modelForm);
            }
        }
```

The problem is that the choice of any value in the field, which is "enableAjaxValidation" => true, immediately leads to the saving of the model (even without pressing the save button). How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller try it like this:

```
$model = new ExampleForm;

// validate any AJAX requests fired off by the form
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

Add this before your `if` statement, and remove `Yii::$app->request->isAjax` from your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Add some thing like below in your form

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => 'example',
            'action' => ['your_action'],
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        ])
```

Comment: It won't help him, because ajax request will still save model. He's action is not handling ajax requests.

Comment: @Yupik but ajax will only happen when they click on save button.

Comment: But he don't want to remove ajax validation on blur, he don't want to save model on ajax validation. And, in your case, it will validate on click send button (one model save) and sending form will save it second time.